# Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys not working

Tags: keyboard, usb, mojave, keybindings

I have a MacBook Pro with touchbar and macOS 10.14.1
I'm using a non apple docking station to which I plugged in an LMP keyboard (Model KB-1243) via USB.

Now I want to use the function keys in IntelliJ as shortcuts without having to press the 'fn' key. So I checked the checkbox 'use F1, F2 etc. keys as standard function keys' but it's not working. I still have to press the fn key. I guess this setting is only for the internal MacBook keyboard, because there it works.

But how can I get it enabled for my external USB-Keyboard?

I just tried it with the Karabiner-Elements, set the function keys to the corresponding function key. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue but found a solution. You can enable/disable the feature by pressing the fn+Esc keys on the LMP keyboard. Apparently it's a feature built in the firmware and can't be adjusted with software. It took me hours to find out...

I tried everything first. I downloaded Fluor, Karabiner, FunctionFlip, nothing worked. Until I found that little leaflet in the box with instructions...

Comment: True ninja trick!!!!

Comment: This saved my life! Thanks a million times.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem seems to be the LMP keyboard. I tested with an official Mac keyboard and it instantly worked! Very annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody needs to know where the <kbd>fn</kbd> key on the LMP keyboard is:

(in case the picture is not loading: It is two rows above the left arrow key.)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the Microsoft keyboard, I needed to click the function lock key, and then the function keys worked as expected no need to change any macOS settings.

[image]